# error opening sqlite database with c++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I was following the example of programming sqlite in c++
http://cplus.about.com/od/howtodothingsin1/a/tutorial-two-With-SQLite-and-c.htm

Here is part of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include "sqlite3.h"

  sqlite3 *db;
  sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
  char message[255];

  // open the database                                                                                                                       
  int db_open = sqlite3_open(dbname, &db);
  if (db_open != SQLITE_OK)
    {
      cout << "Failed to open database " << sqlite3_errstr(db_open) << '\n';
      sqlite3_close(db);
      exit(0);
    }
  cout << "Opened db " << dbname << "OK\n";

  //prepare the sql                                                                                                                          
  int db_prepare = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, strlen(sql) + 1, &stmt, NULL);
  if (db_prepare != SQLITE_OK)
    {
      cout << "Failed to prepare database " << sqlite3_errstr(db_prepare) << '\n';
      sqlite3_close(db);
      exit(0);
    }
```

I got this error suggesting me to use sqlite3_errmsg instead of sqlite3_errstr (which does exist) instead. Why is that?

```
db2class.cpp:31:45: error: use of undeclared identifier 'sqlite3_errstr'; did you mean 'sqlite3_errmsg'?
      cout << "Failed to open database " << sqlite3_errstr(db_open) << '\n';
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                            sqlite3_errmsg
/usr/include/sqlite3.h:2754:24: note: 'sqlite3_errmsg' declared here
SQLITE_API const char *sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3*);
                       ^
db2class.cpp:31:60: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'sqlite3 *' with an lvalue of type 'int'
      cout << "Failed to open database " << sqlite3_errstr(db_open) << '\n';
                                                           ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/sqlite3.h:2754:47: note: passing argument to parameter here
SQLITE_API const char *sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3*);
                                              ^
db2class.cpp:41:48: error: use of undeclared identifier 'sqlite3_errstr'; did you mean 'sqlite3_errmsg'?
      cout << "Failed to prepare database " << sqlite3_errstr(db_prepare) << '\n';
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                               sqlite3_errmsg
/usr/include/sqlite3.h:2754:24: note: 'sqlite3_errmsg' declared here
SQLITE_API const char *sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3*);
                       ^
db2class.cpp:41:63: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'sqlite3 *' with an lvalue of type 'int'
      cout << "Failed to prepare database " << sqlite3_errstr(db_prepare) << '\n';
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/sqlite3.h:2754:47: note: passing argument to parameter here
SQLITE_API const char *sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3*);
```

Comment: See [this link](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/issues/70)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial told you to download the latest SQLite version.

You did not do this, so you're using an older version that does not yet have the `sqlite3_errstr` function.

(BTW; using `sqlite3_errstr` is wrong in this case; `sqlite3_errmsg` returns a message with more useful information.)

Answer (score 0):

Check the sqlite version.

The version where sqlite3_errstr was added was release 2012-12-12 (3.7.15).

Comment: This is accurate and helpful, so thank you for it. Verified this at http://sqlite.org/changes.html (and just search for "sqlite3_errstr").